# PHP/MySQL: Datetime calculation?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySQL table that contains datetime data stored in it.
I need to know if 30 days has passed since the given time.
How can I do this?

Mockup code:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT data FROM myTable LIMIT 1");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($query);
if( days_passed($row['date'], 30) )
     echo "30 days has passed since the given date time.";
```

Comment: Short answer: *WHERE date > '2012-04-17'* (date generated from *date('Y-m-d', strtotime('today + 30 days'))*) Long answer: lots of ways.

Comment: What the format/data type of your `date` field?

Comment: @corbin, that's an answer, you should add it as an answer not a comment.

Comment: @TobyAllen Not quite sure if it's what he's looking for, but based on his selected fields, it may be, so have posted it as an answer :). (I'm really bad at what should and shouldn't be answer -- I always feel weird posting tiny snippets like that as an answer, but I'm way too lazy to type out non-intersting answers half the time.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering the question directly, you can use this function in your if statement.

```
function days_passed($date, $days) {
    $old = new DateTime($date);
    $now = new DateTime();
    $interval = $old->diff($now);
    return ($interval->days >= $days);
}
```

That will return true if the difference between the date provided and now is >= the number of days supplied in the second argument.

However, your may prefer to do this with SQL.

Comment: If you want to know the number of days, it's better to use `$interval->days`. `$interval->d` returns a number that is useful in statements like `1 month and 5 days`.

Answer (score 3):

Altering your query to something like:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, `date`, NOW()) AS days_passed FROM myTable LIMIT 1
```

Will return the number of days since `date`.

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/015c9/2

Answer (score 2):

You can just select the result right from the database;

```
SELECT *, ADDDATE(`date`, INTERVAL 30 DAY) < NOW() more_than_30_days_ago
FROM myTable LIMIT 1;
```

and then use something like;

```
if( $row['more_than_30_days_ago'] )
    echo "30 days has passed since the given date time.";
```

Simple demo of the database part [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2b188/6).

Answer (score 1):

```
$date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('today + 30 days'));
$query = mysql_query("SELECT date FROM tbl WHERE date > '{$date}' LIMIT 1");
if (mysql_num_rows($query)) { ... }
```

In your question you're only pulling the data to check it, so really you don't even need to pull it.  Just use a WHERE clause, and then if a row is pulled, you know it was found.

(If you actually need to process the data farther, or other conditions are involved, one of the other answers is probably better.)

Answer (score 0):

Here is with PHP:

```
$days = 30;
if(date('Y-m-d', strtotime("{$row['date']} +{$days}day")) < date('Y-m-d'))
    echo "More than 30 days has passed";
```